# c++ - Creating class instance in function and using it later

Tags: c++, oop, class, static

Can I do this:

```
static Toggle GetAutoUpdatedToggle(DWORD key, bool initialState = false)
{
    Toggle tempToggle(key, initialState);
    autoUpdateToggles.push_back(tempToggle); //This is static member - std::vector<Toggle>
    return tempToggle;
}
```

And I'm also using it later like that:

```
void Toggle::UpdateAllFromFactory() //This is static function
{
    for each (Toggle toggle in autoUpdateToggles)
    {
        toggle.Update();
    }
}
```

Is this good way of doing it?

---

**UPDATE 1 - After your suggestoins:**

```
static Toggle* GetAutoUpdatedToggle(DWORD key, bool initialState = false)
{
    Toggle *pToggle = new Toggle(key, initialState);
    m_autoUpdateToggles.push_back(pToggle);
    return pToggle;
}

void Toggle::UpdateAllFromFactory()
{
    for (std::vector<Toggle*>::iterator it = m_autoUpdateToggles.begin(); it < m_autoUpdateToggles.end(); it++)
    {
        (*it)->Update();
    }
}
```

Comment: You could return index to the std::vector instead of Toggle instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not a good way of doing it, because you pass around *copies* of `Toggle`:

- `GetAutoUpdatedToggle` returns a *copy* of the `Toggle` that it just pushed into the `vector`. It's not in itself a wrong thing to do, but any manipulations the caller may do on the returned toggle would not be reflected on the one you pushed onto the `vector`
- The `for` loop goes through elements of the `vector`, creating a copy for use inside the loop body. Unless the `Toggle` itself has a pointer-like semantic, the `Update()` action would not be reflected on `Toggle` objects inside the `vector`.

To fix this issue, make `GetAutoUpdatedToggle` return a *reference* to the `Toggle` object that it just pushed onto the `vector`, and use a `vector<Toggle>::iterator` object to iterate through the stored toggles. This would let you operate on the actual objects, rather than on their copies.

Comment: Ok. What is the esiet way to get the last pushed element from vector?

Comment: @Hooch This is probably the simplest way to return the last element that you pushed back: `return *autoUpdateToggles.rbegin();`

Comment: I fixed it like that: See Update 1 in my question

Comment: @Hooch Yes, you can use pointers too. However, this puts you in charge of memory management: the 'new' operator call must be countered with a call of 'delete', so you need to take care of that somewhere in your code to avoid memory leaks. An alternative would be to use unique_ptr template instead of a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Your static function returns a copy of the `Toggle`. `.push_back` will also create a copy of the toggle. Thus the `Toggle` you return is not in the `autoUpdateToggles` and cannot be updated later.

```
Toggle myToggle = GetAutoUpdatedToggle(key);
/* ... */

Toggle alternativToggle = myToggle;
// alternativToggle == myToggle is true
Toggle::UpdateAllFromFactory();

// alternativToggle == myToggle is still true
```

Also note that your current implementation of `Toggle::UpdateAllFromFactory();` uses copies of Toggles if you didn't use iterators instead.

You'll have to provide a *handle*  to your `Toggle` object. This can be a simple pointer or any other object that doesn't loose the identity of the specific `Toggle` when being copied.

Comment: So I should create pointer to class inside that function. and in vector I should keep pointers? I'm always confused by this. I program a lot in c#

Comment: If you use C++11 you could use `std::shared_ptr`.